# Find all the partial paths in a tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I am trying to create a Haskell function that generates a list containing all the partial paths of a tree, given the tree implementation `data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`. For example, if I have a tree

```
tree = Node 5 (Node 3 Empty Empty ) (Node 2 Empty Empty )
```

I want to get

```
[[],[5],[5,3],[5,2]]
```

How could I make such a function?

Comment: Hello! Please take a minute and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, if you do, probably you will delete this answer and create a new one, and you will receive a lot of help, indeed, I know the answer (and I can count  6 users in my head that by sure also knows it), but this is not a free code factory, you will understand if you read the link. I hope you can create soon the new question or edit this one soon. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

First let us consider the type of this function, it must be `Tree a ->  [[a]]`.

So what can we do given a node `Node x left right`? We have the path that is just the node itself - this is just `[x]`, as well as the paths that go through this node to the left- and right sub tree. The paths going throu the left and right sub tree are just what we get if we apply our function to `left` and `right` respectively. We now just need to add `x` to the start of each of those paths and we do that by calling `map(x:) paths`. (And for an empty one we should get an empty list as there is no path.)

```hs
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
tree = Node 5 (Node 3 Empty Empty ) (Node 2 Empty Empty )

pp :: Tree a -> [[a]]
pp (Node x left right) = [[x]] ++ map(x:)(pp left) ++ map(x:)(pp right)
pp Empty = []
```

Now this has one flaw that the empty path is not considered as a partial path by this function. But we can easily amend that by adding it and wrapping it in another function:

```hs
partialPaths :: Tree a -> [[a]]
partialPaths t = [[]] ++ pp t

main = print $ partialPaths tree
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY09D8IgEIZ3fsUNDpDGRePSpG6uxsGNMFxStERaCb0BE/87QqnGGheOvF9Ph@NNWxtji4Rw9loDQgOH3tEDnnC8t1ngxRCfD6N8m@LvgE93O9fKK2Z1s1QZcw7q@o1a70FKVCqrJR/A6guBN9eOREJIGZSCqoIeHQ@14CmZE@JHK4W8U0ipqRIMPRm0J6Ru/Iv99mnCFVraIcZ6NEMSnTcDwQqW6TQV4ws)

Comment: Please do not provide solutions to homework problems, given the user did not show any attempt to solve it. See https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't consider that this might be a homework problem. I received (and still do) a lot of help from other Haskellers when starting out, even with seemingly trivial problems, and now hoped to also help other beginner to get started.

Comment: well helping is definitely a good idea. But the idea is that the user first makes a fair attempt. Usually in the answer, we can then explain what is not working with that attempt, and give extra tips to improve (efficiency, elegance, etc.)

Comment: Yes I agree - however sometimes one doesn't even know where to start. But in this case I just didn't consider this possibility.

Comment: perhaps you can rewrite your answer to one that gives "hints". For examply by describing the process how to come up with a solution, but leaving some aspects blank such that the OP can fill these in :).

Comment: what if we have `tree = Node 5 (Node 3 tree Empty ) (Node 2 Empty Empty )`? :) can we see `2` in the output? (also, here's the [SO meta post about homeworks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions))

Comment: @WillNess If you're willing to wait for an eternity:P

Comment: isn't there another option, perhaps? ... ;)

Comment: @WillNess Now I'm curious to know what you mean:) My thought its that now it could be considered as a graph with a cycle (that isn't a tree anymore), but I don't think we can detect this cycle without making any assumptions, or we consider it as an infinite tree in which case there are infinitely many partial paths. What were you hinting at?

Comment: your code makes a preorder traversal of a tree, which is a variation on *depth first* traversal. but you could code up a *breadth first* traversal - either by hand, with queues, or approximately, by replacing `++` with `diagonalize` from "universe" package / "Omega" monad / etc. (one example is [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97610/2909))

Comment: @WillNess but wouldn't that still result in an infinite output for your example?

Comment: an infinite list for sure but such that will have 2 - and any other node -  at a *finite* index. unlike with your enumeration, for my example tree.  (for other examples, search @chi's answers for "omega dovetailing", or Daniel Wagner's for "universe", I think)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200962/discussion-between-will-ness-and-flawr).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, thanks for explaining. And thanks for pointing  out the Omega monad, that could come in handy in golfing tasks:) (Do you know [ppcg.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)? We do even have a [haskell chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men)!)